# System.Web.Mvc.dll Source Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to improve a very powerfull OutputCaching for my project that will be compatible with mobile caching and intreval taking from sql. I'm looking for System.Web.Mvc.dll source code.

Any links, clues will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the ASP.NET Web Framework code (MVC, Web API, Web Pages) is opensource and can viewed at any time on the Git site:

Asp.Net
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack

Asp.Net Core
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore

https://source.dot.net/

Comment: Sadly, that's not uncommon. Thankfully, Microsoft began to see the light some years ago and has pretty much made everything new they do in .NET opensource Nuget packages. Entity Framework is also opensource. This allows the community to contribute and also harden the codebase and (by virtue of Nuget) allows Microsoft to release updates to these components independent of .NET Framework point releases.

Answer (score 3):

Find the github links below:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/tree/master/src/System.Web.Mvc